# Angular: How to use a component dynamically in another component?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material

I have an DialogService for Angular Material:

```
constructor(private dialog: MatDialog){}

openDialog(dialogData){
        const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(DialogComponent, {
                data: dialogData
       }
}
```

and a DialogComponent to open the dialog with:

```
let componentToRender

constructor(@Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public dialogData){
       this.componentToRender = dialogdata.componentToRender
}
```

and this template for it:

```
<div class="dialog">
        <ng-container></ng-container> // Here i want to dynamically render a given component
</div>
```

I want to give my dialogService with the dialogData a reference to an component that i want to be rendered inside my diaologComponent `<ng-container>`

The result should be, that i can call my service with a reference to a component to open a dialog container that renders this given component inside the component.html's ng-container. For example like so:

```
let dialogData = {}

dialogData.componentToRender = COMPONENT_TO_RENDER_INSIDE_OF_DIALOG

this.dialogService.openDialog(dialogData)
```

The idea is to make something like a dialog-container where the body can be any component i want to render inside of the dialog-container

I hope it is enough to write only the essential code, because I ask this question from another computer and could not copy paste the stuff I already have. thank you :)

Comment: what about router-outlet ?

Comment: router-outlet does not help me because the dialog will not have a path.
But i want to create something like a router-outlet inside my dialogComponent.html

Answer (score 0):

For now I kind of solved this with `ViewContainerRef`.
I use the `createComponent()` method and give it the Component I want to render.
Then I insert the create ref inside my ng-template.

```
@ViewChild('container', {read: ViewContainerRef}) container!: ViewContainerRef

const componentRef = this.viewContainerRef.createComponent(MY_COMPONENT_DYNAMICALLY_GIVEN)
this.container.insert(componentRef.hostView)
```

This works but also renders my component selector tag around my content.

```
<my_inserted_component> <!-- I need to get rid of this :D -->
       <!-- contents of my_inserted_component -->
</my_inserted_component>
```

That sadly results into Layouting problems. So now I need to find out how to change my CSS or (better) how to get rid of the outer tag with the component selector name.

EDIT: Also I should mention that I am on Angular 14